# Reload data controller json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hello here's my json :

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAAAAA",
        "data": "False",
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBBBB",
        "data": "45%",
    },
    {
        "name": "CCCCCC",
        "data": "12%",
    },
    {
        "name": "DDDDDD",
        "data": "False",
    }
]
```

My javascript :

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
        app.service('service', function($http, $q){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('names.json').then(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            this.getNames = function() {
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });
        app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http, $route) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.reloadData = function(){
            $route.reload();
        }
            var promise = service.getNames();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.names = data.data;
                console.log($scope.names);
            }
        );
```

HTML :

```
    <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
                <td>{{name.name}}</td>
                <td>{{name.date}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

<button ng-click="FirstCtrl.reloadData()">Reload</button>
```

I want to reload data in controller from json, in reloadData() function but it didn't work. After click on the button Reload nothing happens.
Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: Do you see the log of `$scope.names` ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: any error in console, i see log of $scope.names @Olli

Answer (score 0):

ok try `$window.location.reload();` in place of `$route.reload();` or you can apply refresh function.

`$route.reload()` is used to refresh route and `$window.location.reload();` is used to refresh the page.

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$window.location.reload()` but remember that this will restart the App so any function after it may not be performed so you have to place it strategically after what you want done is done.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few problems with the code you supplied. I fixed a few of them and made your code work. You can view it here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/DpRUJg520yew91t93oVr

This is the script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('service', function($http, $q){

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('names.json').then(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            this.getNames = function() {
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });

  app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.reloadData = function(){
          console.log("reloading");
            vm.loadData();
        };

        vm.loadData = function(){
           var promise = service.getNames();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.names = data.data;
                console.log($scope.names);
            });
        }

      vm.loadData();
  });
```

Comment: now reload only data in console.log, but table dont reload @Shai Aharoni